What does ‘(A)’ mean in SMARTS pattern when using Chemicalize to draw the chemical structure?
I am not quite sure what ‘(A)’ could mean for the carbon atom when writing the SMARTS CCN(C)C using Chemicalize to draw the chemical structure below. Can anyone help?


According to Daylight Chemical Information Systems — SMARTS Theory Manual and Chemaxon docs — SMARTS, the capital letter ‘A’ in SMARTS notation is a label for an aliphatic primitive (atom).
Chemaxon’s JChem query puts requested SMARTS atom properties in braces next to the corresponding atomic labels when drawn with Marvin.
