What does ‘S/A’ mean in SMARTS pattern when using Chemicalize to draw the chemical structure?
I am still new to the SMARTS annotation. I am wondering what does S/A’ mean on the bond labeling drawn with Chemicalize using SMARTS [!#1]c1n[cH]nc([!#1])c1[!#1]? Does it mean “single or aromatic query bond type”?


The earlier post should be linked https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/182987/what-does-a-mean-in-smarts-pattern-when-using-chemicalize-to-draw-the-chemic

The ‘S/A’ here is not the part of SMARTS annotation, rather Marvin's query descriptor. Yes, according to Chemaxon docs — Features exported to CDX, ‘S/A’ refers to “single or aromatic query bond type”.
